# How to Append Html5 Select (dropdownlist) with html control(like label)

Tags: jquery, html

i have one dropdowlist

```
<select id="dllSec" onchange="SaveQuestionValues(this);">
               <option value="select">select</option>
               <option value="No">No</option>
               <option value="Yes">YES</option>
           </select>
```

> i made clone of it.

```
var cloneSecQues = $("#dllSec").clone();
```

> Now if i append it without any html control it works fine.like

```
$("#SecQuestions").append(cloneSecQues);
```

> but iam unable to append it with html controls.like

```
$("#SecQuestions").append('<label id="lblAsk">'+cloneSecQues+'<label>');
```

> it shows [object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `outerHTML` string, right now you are concatenating a `Jquery object` with a `string`,

```
$("#SecQuestions").append('<label id="lblAsk">' + cloneSecQues[0].outerHTML + '<label>');
```

Or you can do like,

```
$("#SecQuestions").append($('<label id="lblAsk"><label>').append(cloneSecQues));
```

[**Procedural demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pndmh2v6/)

Comment: thanks alot Rajaprabhu Aravindasam,it works fine now